# Simplifying Boolean expression $B'D' + CD' + ABC'D$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm struggling with simplifying $B'D' + CD' + ABC'D$.

Isn't it that it's already simplified? I tried doing $(B' + C)(D'+D) + ABC'D$ to get $B'+C+ABC'D$, but I am getting different truth tables.

What should the steps be?

EDIT:

I now have the following steps:

So, basically, I have

$D'(B'+C)+ABC'D$ to

$D'(B+C)+D(ABC')$

$(D'+D)((B+C)+ABC')$

$B'+C+ABC'$

Can it be simplified any further?

Comment: It should be $(B'+C)D' +ABC'D$ if I read that correctly (for just the one step you attempted)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So, basically, I have

$D'(B'+C)+ABC'D$ to 

$D'(B+C)+D(ABC')$ to
$(D'+D)((B+C)+ABC')$ to
$B'+C+ABC'$

Comment: I should revise my other comment as $B'+C=(BC')'$.  So you get $(BC')'D'+(BC')AD$ as a next step.

Comment: That lets you treat $BC'$ as a single quantity, so we could relabel it as $E$ and work with $E'D'+EAD$.

Comment: A trick that may help is to introduce "and $1$" using $A$: $(A+A')E'D'+EAD$, leading to $AED+AE'D'+A'E'D'$ and then $A(E'D'+ED)+A'E'D'$, but there's nothing obvious about this to move further.

Comment: @abiessu, can you give a comment on my simplification embedded in my question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the answer given sums up the situation.  There really isn't a further simplification available.  Were you given information to suggest that there should be?  The system note that both $B'+C$ and $BC'$ can be written more concisely is only a labeling simplification; the original quantities should be restored in the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

The original expression is as simplified as it can be.

In your EDIT, the step from:

$D'(B +C) + D(ABC')$

to:

$(D'+D)((B+C)+ABC')$

is incorrect.  That is like saying that $ab+cd=(a+c)(b+d)$, which from basic algebra you should know is not correct

Comment: (Also noting that getting $B+C$ from $B'+C$ is a problem...)

Comment: @abiessu Fortunately, the OP goes the other way around in the last step. Two wrongs make a right? :P